# 404 error after removing id from url in joomla

Tags: joomla

Hello i need some help to solve a problem.
I have a joomla site 3.3.3 version and i removed the id's from url according to this.[https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/988/remove-article-id-from-joomla-3-url][1]

Everything works ok.When i created an Articles-Newsflash (advanced) module and assign articles to it,by clicking the link title it give's me 404 error page.
When i go to the admin area and turn Sef Advanced Mode to no everything works!
I can't figure out what i'm missing.
Thank's in advance for any help!!
P.S.Its a multilingual site.

Comment: Please upgrade to the latest joomla first, or you will get hacked...

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have articles with the same aliases, even trashed articles. Check your trash for deleted articles and completely trash them.

By the way, we created an exhaustive guide, and it is available here: http://www.itoctopus.com/how-to-remove-the-article-id-from-joomlas-sef-urls

There is also a way, described in the guide, of doing this whole thing without modifying a core file.

Comment: @ itoctopus first thank's a lot for the answer.But i already did everything i have even add to \com_content\config.xml a fieldset so to change the status from the admin but still no luck.Clicking to article gives 404.Any suggestion?